# Android Studio dialect letter not working

Tags: android-studio

I am having a question regarding dialect letter "Ć" (Shift + Alt + c) which is not working (not visible) on Android Studio. I sometimes need it in the comments. How can I use the letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off the shortcut you said you use, and that other characters work, that leaves one issue: The shortcut is already used. As seen [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts), by default, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (Alt-Shift or Shift-Alt is irrelevant) maps to "View recent changes", which is a part of the VCS. Alternatively, it might map to something else, if you've configured it already.

Try remapping (or remove if you don't use it and don't want to use it) to something else. This can be done under File -> Settings ->  Keymap. Search for "View recent changes" if you can't find it, or alternatively search by shortcut.

This would likely work for other keybinds where Android Studio (or IntelliJ for that matter) overrides dialect combos, although those likely map to different actions. Aside searching for it in AS directly by name or keybind, you can also search on the website I linked earlier if you prefer that (but note that it's only valid for the default shortcuts).

Answer (score 2):

You can check your key shortcuts and should be sure empty `Alt + Shift + c`.  And you can change character encoding(ISO 8859-1) in here [image: here]

[image]

Comment: Encoding is correct, all other Polish special characters are visible (e.g. Ą, ę, etc)

Comment: Did you check shortcuts in keymap? in settings/preferences? Because I can see in my editor when I copy pasted

Comment: I am not sure how can I find such shortcut, if there is any?

Comment: I added plus one for you as well :-)